# Can I use / view Ubuntu software online?

Tags: unity

I like to use / view Ubuntu software online. I meet a lot of people who don't know Ubuntu, and sometimes I want to show them more than screen shots / recording.

Is there any way I can show them Ubuntu software like Nautilus / Shotwell / Firefox / Libreoffice/ Unity interface online?

Comment: I don't want them to browse the software-center i want them to VIEW/USE ubuntu software like nautilus shotwell and possibly the entire unity interface.

Comment: Ah, you might want to try http://ubuntu.com/tour then

Comment: @jokerdino thanks, looks good, it's not the real deal, but that is to be expected from html* writen os... btw i found this link https://try.cloud.ubuntu.com/ to try cloud.ubuntu. I don't know what cloud.UBUNTU is (something with storage?) but i saw a while back a linux-os which you can use via webbrowser (Y-os/eyeos???) is that the same thing as cloud.ubuntu.com. try ubuntu out via webbrowser?

Comment: Wow it's possible http://cloud.ubuntu.com/2010/11/show-off-ubuntu-desktop-on-cloud/

Comment: It may be too late to save this question with editing (3 close votes already) but maybe a new one 'Can I show people an interactive Ubuntu desktop demo online'? @Anwar's answer below would be perfect, it's what I show people. For some reason, even other experienced computer users sometimes think Ubuntu & Linux has no GUI, and is command line only. They are shocked when I show them the tour. Go figure...

Answer (score 8):

Go to http://www.ubuntu.com/tour/en/.  You can directly show them the awesome Ubuntu software center from within your browser!!.

You should have flash plugin installed in Firefox. If you use chrome, you will be fine. To install flash use the below link:

### [flashplugin-installer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/flashplugin-installer) [image: Install flashplugin-installer]

or using this command in terminal

```
 sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Here is a screenshot running Ubuntu software center (full demo Ubuntu actually) inside a browser

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could definitely run an Ubuntu instance on some cloud provider and use VNC to "show" it.  You can also use the web Gtk backend [like this](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/gtk-32-released-with-html5-allows.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can record your monitor screen or your can click photos of your desktop.

To Click Photos :

- Press the screenshot button on your keyboard.
- For further information visit [this link.](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/screen-shot-record.html)

To record your desktop :

- Install an application called *recordmydesktop*

  > sudo apt-get install *recordmydesktop recordmydesktop-gtk*
- For further information visit [this link.](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/24742/record-screen-activity-in-ubuntu-with-recordmydesktop/)